# Find the generators and group description of a set of matrices

Tags: matrix, group-theory

I have the following matrix elements:

```
m:={ {{1, 0, 0 }, {0,  1,  0}, { 0,  0,  1}},
     {{6, 0, 0 }, {0,  0,  1}, {11, 11, 11}},
     {{8, 0, 0 }, {1,  1,  1}, { 4, 11, 12}},
     {{9, 0, 0 }, {4, 11, 12}, { 0,  2,  0}} };
```

I want to know how I can find the group of $m$ and its generators.

I have tried to use the following:

```
GroupElements[PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 0, 0 },{0, 1, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1 }},
                                       {{ 6, 0, 0 },{ 0, 0, 1 },{ 11,11,11}},
                                       {{ 8, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, { 4, 11, 12 }},
                                       {{ 9, 0, 0 }, {4, 11, 12},{0,2, 0 }]}]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: What do you mean by the "group of $m$"? That's not a Cayley table, so I can discount that. It's not a set of permutations. Can you give a little more information about what it means to be the "group of a matrix"? If you give those details, we might be able to help

Comment: Since `m` is a constant, write `m = `, not `m := `

Comment: The set of permutations are [ {}, {1,2,5,10,11,12,7,8,9,3,4,6}{13,14,17,19,20,21}{15,16,18,22,23,24}, {1,3,7,10}{2,4,8,11}{5,6,9,12}{13,15,19,22}{14,16,20,23}{17,18,21,24},
  {1,4,9,7,11,5}{2,6,3,8,12,10}{13,16,21,15,20,24,19,23,17,22,14,18}]. So how can know the group of this set and it's generators.

Comment: for example :Let Gens={ {}, {1,2,3,4,6,5}, {1,2}{3,4}{5,6}, {2,4,5}, {2,5,4}, {1,2,6,5,3,4} }; be a set of generators of the group C3 x S3. The question is what is the stabilizer of this group.

I have tried the following :
GroupStabilizer[{}, {1,2,3,4,6,5}, {1,2}{3,4}{5,6}, {2,4,5}, {2,5,4}, {1,2,6,5,3,4}]; but it did not work properly.